# problems changing prefork to worker

Tags: apache2

Apache/2.4.25, PHP 7.3.17 Greetings I am looking to change from prefork to worker and I follow the following steps:

```
a2dismod php7.3
systemctl restart apache2
a2dismod mpm_prefork
a2enmod mpm_worker
systemctl restart apache2
a2enmod php7.3
```

After the last step above I get the error:

```
Considering dependency mpm_prefork for php7.3:
Considering conflict mpm_event for mpm_prefork:
Considering conflict mpm_worker for mpm_prefork:
ERROR: Module mpm_worker is enabled - cannot proceed due to conflicts. It needs to be disabled first!
ERROR: Could not enable dependency mpm_prefork for php7.3, aborting
```

What can I do to make the worker work?

Comment: Remember, that php7.3 cannot be enabled using mpm_event or mpm_worker. You must use an alternative such as PHP-FPM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use mpm_event or mpm_worker, php7.3 i.e the php module for apache will not work.

You must install an alternative such as PHP-FPM. Make sure you have atleast 2 GB of RAM for PHP-FPM

To install PHP-FPM, do the following:

```
a2dismod php7.3
a2dismod mpm_prefork
a2enmod mpm_worker
systemctl restart apache2
apt install php-fpm -y
a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
a2enconf php7.3-fpm
systemctl start php7.3-fpm
systemctl restart apache2
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.apache2

> PHP-FPM actually provides you with way better performance than the PHP module.